# diffraction grating

Tags: optics, diffraction

Can I design a diffraction grating that has only two orders of diffraction, with the second one has a zero intensity?

So the first order of diffraction would be bright and the weak light from far stars could be analyzed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need blazed diffraction grating:

[image]

You don't really need to design it - they are manufactured in volume for spectrum analyzers, for example here: http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=26 . You may also check tutorial there, and a mandatory wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazed_grating

Comment: so I'm asking about the concept of making such thing , not because I want to design one by myself